# Android layout with scrolling middle and fixed button bar at bottom of screen (button bar not showing)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a screen layout but I am having a problem.

It has a Toolbar (being set as the action bar), a scrolling pane and a button bar at the bottom which is fixed to the bottom of the screen always visible.

For some reason though the button bar and buttons are not visible even if I scroll to the bottom of the screen, there is no sign of them.

Below is my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <ScrollView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtConnectionName"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Database Connection Name"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtServer"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Server"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtUsername"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtPassword"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtDatabase"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Database"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtPort"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="6"
                        android:hint="Port"
                        android:text="3306"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/db_chkStorePassword"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/store_password"
                    android:checked="true" />
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/db_chkConnectViaSSHTunnel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Connect via SSH Tunnel"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="SSH Connection Settings" />
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtSSHHost"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="SSH Host"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtSSHUsername"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="SSH Username"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtSSHPassword"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="SSH Password"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/db_txtSSHPort"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="SSH Port"
                            android:text="22"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:inputType="number"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Leave database blank to connect to any database on this server" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
            <Button android:id="@+id/db_btnTest"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Test Connection" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/db_btnCreateEdit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Create"
                android:enabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put layout_above in scrollview

Comment: @Keshav Doesn't seem to work, I've also tried layout_below but no difference

Comment: Button width is 0dp?

Comment: @Keshav it does but it has the layout_weight set 1 so it fills the space evenly